# Lex bot getting value only in digit representation not from words

Tags: bots, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am a newbie to Amazon Lex, I have created a bot that offers several services:

- open a case
- check status
- status via email

when a user checks the status, he is forced to provide a "**case number**." The issue I am facing is that it only gets value from digits such as [digit representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Lz6.png).

When the user uses "nine" instead of 9, it doesn't work. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlUmF.png).

Guide me on that issue, I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: The correct tag for questions about Amazon Lex is [amazon-lex], not [lex]. The [lex] tag is about lex the lexer generator and thus not related to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an AWS Lambda will be best suited to assist you with what you're trying to achieve.

When testing via the AWS Lex console, click the *"Inspect"* button and view the JSON-formatted requests and responses.

What you will find is that when the user enters a numeric value in words - as in your example *"nine"* instead of *"9"* - Lex will provide you with the original input as well as the numeric form of the input.

Take a look at the JSON payload below that I've extracted from my own example:

```
{
   "messages":[
      {
         "content":"Well done!",
         "contentType":"PlainText"
      }
   ],
   "sessionState":{
      "dialogAction":{
         "type":"Close"
      },
      "intent":{
         "name":"MainIntent",
         "slots":{
            "quantity":{
               "value":{
                  "originalValue":"two",
                  "interpretedValue":"2",
                  "resolvedValues":[
                     "2"
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "state":"ReadyForFulfillment",
         "confirmationState":"None"
      },
      "originatingRequestId":"e309a92b-124b-4250-bbd3-2fb8891aa90f"
   },
   "interpretations":[
      {
         "nluConfidence":{
            "score":1
         },
         "intent":{
            "name":"MainIntent",
            "slots":{
               "quantity":{
                  "value":{
                     "originalValue":"two",
                     "interpretedValue":"2",
                     "resolvedValues":[
                        "2"
                     ]
                  }
               }
            },
            "state":"ReadyForFulfillment",
            "confirmationState":"None"
         }
      },
      {
         "intent":{
            "name":"FallbackIntent",
            "slots":{
               
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "sessionId":"858917309331613"
}
```

Have a look at the ***interpretedValue*** field in the payload. This is the numeric value that you're looking for.

Using a Lambda function, you can extract this value and perform any validation that you may need before continuing with the rest of the flow or user journey.

You can find out more about integrating Lambda functions into Lex from the developer guide:

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/lambda.html
```